# Issue using libsdl2-image-2.0-0

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl-2

Recently I've been playing around with the SDL library and wanted to start using libsdl2-image-2.0-0 along with SDL. I have been trying to get this working with Ubuntu 15.04. I have installed the package using

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-image-2.0-0
```

The installation appeared to go completely fine but when I try to include the image library in my C++ code with

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

I get an error "fatal error: SDL2/SDL_image.h: No such file or directory"
I went and looked where the SDL2 base library was located /usr/local/include/SDL2 and just as the error message said SDL_image.h was not there.
I then tried to figure out where the library was using

```
apt-file search SDL_image.h
```

When I do this

```
libsdl-image1.2-dev: /usr/include/SDL/SDL_image.h
libsdl2-image-dev: /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h
```

both show up as results. This is strange to me since I did not install libsdl2-image-dev. Also when I try to view /usr/include/SDL2/ the folder doesn't even appear to exist which just adds to my confusion.

I then tried to remove libsdl2-image-dev so I could install libsdl2-image-2.0-0 but when I run the command

```
sudo apt-get remove libsdl2-image-dev
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libsdl2-image-dev' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

and when I try to run the command

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

I end up getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsdl2-2.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

So basically I cannot locate where this library is and so I can't properly link it to my code. Is there a more reliable way to locate where this library is and is there something fundamental I am not understanding in regards to using these supplementary libraries?

Answer (score 1):

You need the development packages installed to develop SDL2 based programs.

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-image-dev
```

Comment: I was able to build a basic application using the base library even though I do not have the dev version of libsdl2. My main issue is I cannot locate where the version of libsdl2-image that I have currently installed is. I would like to at least try that library if possible. That being said I did try to install libsdl2-dev and I hit a bunch of dependency issues:  "libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed" 
I installed these and this message still persists.